# Uploading an image file with Express.js, React, and MySQL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I need to make a page where a specific user (in this case an admin) can upload an image, save it on my mySQL database, and also in the 'uploads' folder in Express. In addition to that, I need a way to display the image later so that other users can see it when they log in. Are there any helpful packages on NPM that make this easier? Or is there a way to do this through vanilla React and Express?

Answer (score 1):

Try following package for Node - https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

```
var multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: function (req, file, cb) {

    cb(null, appRoot+"/Uploads")

  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {

    cb(null, commonFunctions.generateAccessToken(90)+'.'+file.originalname.split('.')[1])

  }

})
global.upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

Then in your routes add upload middleware -

```
router.post("/addPersonalDetail", [upload.single("profile_pic") ], Controllers.serviceController.addPersonalDetail);
```

In your controller single filename is accessible via-

```
data.profile_pic_name = (request.file) ? request.file.filename : "";
```

Multiple Files are accessible via -

```
request.files[0].filename
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot.